# A polynomial olympiad Question

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, contest-math

If *a,b,c,x* are real numbers such that *abc $\neq$ 0* and
   *$\frac{xb+(1-x)c}{a}$ = $\frac{xc+(1-x)a}{b}$ = $\frac{xa+(1-x)b}{c}$*.
Then prove that either *a+b+c = 0 or a=b=c*.
    It is an indian olympiad question and is very hard for me. Can you guys help me out please??

Comment: If you see nothing else, you can clear fractions in the first pair and set $A=a^2-bc, B=b^2-ac, C=c^2-ab$ to obtain $(A+B)x=A$. Other pairs give similar. Not as slick as spotting nice ways through, and needs some more work. Quite often you simply need to work with what you have and persist - what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rearrange:

$$\frac{xb+(1-x)c}{a}=\frac{xc+(1-x)a}{b}$$
$$xb^2+(1-x)bc=xac+(1-x)a^2$$
$$x(b^2-ac)=(1-x)(a^2-bc)$$

Repeating this for another equality we obtain:-

$\frac{x}{1-x}=\frac{b^2-ac}{c^2-ab}=\frac{a^2-bc}{b^2-ac}$

$(b^2-ac)^2=(c^2-ab)(a^2-bc)$

$a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$

$(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)=0$

$a+b+c=0$ or $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2=0$

$a+b+c=0$ or $a=b=c$

Comment: Can you explain the first step

Comment: I just multiplied out an equality of the question and collected up the x terms and the (1-x) terms. Then repeated this for another equality

Comment: Still can't understand add few steps in the answer

Comment: OK but I'm a slow typist!

Comment: thank you for rewriting

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the property: $ \frac{\displaystyle x}{\displaystyle y} = \frac{\displaystyle z}{\displaystyle t} = \frac{\displaystyle m}{\displaystyle n} = \frac{\displaystyle x+z+m}{\displaystyle y+t+n}$

Answer (score 0):

Just assume all the equalities equal to a constant $k$ $\dfrac{xb+(1-x)c}{a}$ $=$ $\dfrac{xc+(1-x)a}{b}$ $= $$\dfrac{xa+(1-x)b}{c}$$=$$k$

You get 
${xb+(1-x)c}=k\cdot a$ ; ${xc+(1-x)a}=k\cdot b$ ; ${xa+(1-x)b}=k\cdot c$ Add up all these you get $(a+b+c)=k(a+b+c)$

Either $a+b+c$=$1$; or $k=1$
Now proceed with $k=1$ and solve up all the equations you will end up with $a=b=c$